# Having Issue on Getting Metabox Checkbox Value

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, metabox

I have a Custom Post Type with two Metabox attached as:

```
$offerPrice = isset( $productValuesl['offer_box'] ) ? esc_attr( $productValuesl['offer_box'][0] ) : '';    
$offer = isset( $productValuesl['is_offered'] ) ? esc_attr( $productValuesl['is_offered'][0] ) : '';

<tr>
<td ><label for="price_box">Product Price : </label></td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="price_box" id="price_box" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" /></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td align="" style=""><label for="is_offered">Show Offer :</label></td> 
<td align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="is_offered" id="is_offered" <?php checked( $offer, 'on' ); ?> /></td>
```

now in my custom wp-query I would like to display the price ONLY if the check box is checked so I did a loop as:

```
if ($meta['is_offered'][0]==true){
  echo '<div class="ptitle"><p class="price">$'.$meta['offer_box'][0]. '</p></div>';
}
```

but it is not doing the job! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?
Here is the entire code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'sunglassesCPT', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'  );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
echo '<div class="thumbnail text-center">';
echo '<div class="productImgBox" style="height:220px;">';
the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive', 'href' =>$thumb_url));
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="caption">';
echo '<h4 class="product-title">'.the_title().'</h4>';
if ($meta['is_offered'][0]==true){
  echo '<div class="ptitle"><p class="price">$'.$meta['offer_box'][0]. '</p></div>';
}
echo '<p><a href="'.$thumb_url.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-brown group1" title="Rumi Optical Eyeglasses" role="button">Quick View</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Please dont post same question in a network. You have already posted this in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might want to do is add this code to the output:

```
<pre><?php print_r($meta); ?></pre>
```

Then have a look and make sure you are accessing the correct array keys.

Once your sure, I think you need to verify checkboxes against a value of on or off. So you may need to change this line:

```
if ($meta['is_offered'][0]==true){
```

... to this ...

```
if ($meta['is_offered'][0] === on){
```